# Интеграция html кода в файл с расширением php

Tags: php, html

Суть проблемы такова: была сделана верстка для сайта, а позже html часть верстки была перенесена в новый файл с расширением php, в итоге в браузере html код отображается как текст и никак не читается браузером.
Вот код в редакторе 
[image]

[image]

А вот итог 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, присылайте весь код не в скриншотах, а в форматированном виде.

Answer (score 2):

**php** файлы предназначены для сервера (хостинга) - там будет работать в точности как html.
Просто поменяйте расширение с index.php на index.html

Comment: Ахаха, человек сделал .html => .php, а вы ему советуете вернуть назад :)

Comment: А зачем человеку менять расширение на .php если он в данном случае совсем не используется

Answer (score 2):

Файлы php читаются браузером как текст. Локально открыть его не получится. Чтобы php отображался корректно, нужен веб-сервер c поднятым php (Например LAMP или OSPanel)

Comment: Спасибо. Раньше я не задумывался об этом. И просто верстал то на хостинге то на локалке.

Answer (score 1):

Для вашего же блага можете установить какой-нибудь локальный сервер, например Denwer ( старенький , но думаю вам подойдет ). 
А если разбираться и вовсе не хотите, заходите в гугл введете бесплатный хостинг, там их много ,скидываете свои файлы на один из них и видите долгожданный результат.